# Searching an item from string builder object

Tags: asp.net

```
StringBuilder displayList = new StringBuilder();
```

I have added a few items in displayList
but in my code i need to search for an item in displayList how can i search an item added to 
displayList please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search until you convert it to string using the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.tostring.aspx) method.

Comment: `string result = displayList.ToString();`. Now go ahead and search the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder displayList = new StringBuilder();
        displayList.Append( "ABC" );
        string toFind = "B";
        if( displayList.ToString().Contains(toFind) ) {
            //found it
        }
```